# How do interlocks work with relation trigger steps in buildbot?

Tags: triggers, locks, buildbot

Any one know how interlocks work regarding trigger steps i.e. if a builder hold an exclusive lock over a builddir will it's trigger steps also inherit that lock or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no inheritance of locks between trigger-able steps and it's caller.